# Non-static method cannot be refered from a static context JAVAFX

Tags: java, javafx

So I'm trying to bind my Numpad keys so i can use them in my calculator app but when I try to send my keyEvent as a string from my MainWindow.java to my MainWindowController public void method it gives me the error "Non-static method cannot be refered from a static context" even though none of my classes are static?
Here is the MainWindow code:

```
package main`import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class MainWindow extends Application implements EventHandler<KeyEvent> {


private static Stage historyStage;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MainWindowInterface.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load());
    scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.setTitle("Calculator");
    stage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("../images/icon.png")));
    ((MainWindowController)loader.getController()).init(stage);
    stage.show();
    //scene.setOnKeyPressed(MainWindowController.handle());
    scene.setOnKeyPressed(this);
    scene.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE){
            stage.close();
        }
    });
    createHistoryStage();
}

public void createHistoryStage() throws Exception{
    historyStage = new Stage();
    historyStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    historyStage.setTitle("Calculator History");
    historyStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    historyStage.setResizable(false);
    historyStage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("../images/icon.png")));
    historyStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
}

public static Stage getHistoryStage(){
    return historyStage;
}

public void run() {
    launch();
}

@Override
public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
    String valueOfKey = String.valueOf(event.getCode());
    MainWindowController.keyPress(valueOfKey);
}
```

}

and here is the MainWindowController file (look at keyPress method)

```
    package main`import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;`;



public class MainWindowController {
    @FXML private Pane titlePane;
    @FXML private ImageView btnMinimize, btnClose;
    @FXML private Label lblResult;

    private double x, y;
    private double num1 = 0;
    private String operator = "+";

    private ArrayList<String> calculation_history = new ArrayList<>();

    public void init(Stage stage) {
        titlePane.setOnMousePressed(mouseEvent -> {
            x = mouseEvent.getSceneX();
            y = mouseEvent.getSceneY();
        });
        titlePane.setOnMouseDragged(mouseEvent -> {
            stage.setX(mouseEvent.getScreenX()-x);
            stage.setY(mouseEvent.getScreenY()-y);
        });

        btnClose.setOnMouseClicked(mouseEvent -> stage.close());
        btnMinimize.setOnMouseClicked(mouseEvent -> stage.setIconified(true));
    }

    public void openHistoryWindow(){
        try{
            FXMLLoader loader2 = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("history.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader2.load();
            Scene historyScene = new Scene(root);
            historyScene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            MainWindow.getHistoryStage().setScene(historyScene);

            HistoryController historyController = loader2.getController();
            historyController.initializeCalculations(calculation_history);
            ((HistoryController)loader2.getController()).init(MainWindow.getHistoryStage());

            MainWindow.getHistoryStage().show();
            historyScene.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
                if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE){
                    MainWindow.getHistoryStage().close();
                }
            });
        }catch (IOException ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }

    public void addCalculation(String num1, String operator, String num2, String result){
        String expression = num1 + " " + operator + " " + num2;
        this.calculation_history.add(expression + " = " + result);
    }

    @FXML
    void onNumberClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        int value = Integer.parseInt(((Pane)event.getSource()).getId().replace("btn",""));
        lblResult.setText(Double.parseDouble(lblResult.getText())==0?String.valueOf((double)value):String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(lblResult.getText())*10+value));
    }



    public void keyPress(String keyPressed){

        int value = 0;
        switch (keyPressed){
            case "NUMPAD1": value = 1;
                lblResult.setText(Double.parseDouble(lblResult.getText())==0?String.valueOf((double)value):String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(lblResult.getText())*10+value));
                break;
            case "NUMPAD2": value = 2;
                lblResult.setText(Double.parseDouble(lblResult.getText())==0?String.valueOf((double)value):String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(lblResult.getText())*10+value));
                break;
            case "NUMPAD3": value = 3;
                lblResult.setText(Double.parseDouble(lblResult.getText())==0?String.valueOf((double)value):String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(lblResult.getText())*10+value));
                break;
            case "NUMPAD4": value = 4;
                lblResult.setText(Double.parseDouble(lblResult.getText())==0?String.valueOf((double)value):String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(lblResult.getText())*10+value));
                break;
            case "NUMPAD5": value = 5;
                lblResult.setText(Double.parseDouble(lblResult.getText())==0?String.valueOf((double)value):String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(lblResult.getText())*10+value));
                break;
            case "NUMPAD6": value = 6;
                lblResult.setText(Double.parseDouble(lblResult.getText())==0?String.valueOf((double)value):String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(lblResult.getText())*10+value));
                break;
            case "NUMPAD7": value = 7;
                lblResult.setText(Double.parseDouble(lblResult.getText())==0?String.valueOf((double)value):String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(lblResult.getText())*10+value));
                break;
            case "NUMPAD8": value = 8;
                lblResult.setText(Double.parseDouble(lblResult.getText())==0?String.valueOf((double)value):String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(lblResult.getText())*10+value));
                break;
            case "NUMPAD9": value = 9;
                lblResult.setText(Double.parseDouble(lblResult.getText())==0?String.valueOf((double)value):String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(lblResult.getText())*10+value));
                break;
            case "NUMPAD0": value = 0;
                lblResult.setText(Double.parseDouble(lblResult.getText())==0?String.valueOf((double)value):String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(lblResult.getText())*10+value));
                break;
            default: break;
        }
    }

    @FXML
    void onSymbolClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        String symbol = ((Pane)event.getSource()).getId().replace("btn","");
        if(symbol.equals("Equals")) {
            double num2 = Double.parseDouble(lblResult.getText());
            switch (operator) {
                case "+" -> lblResult.setText((num1+num2) + "");
                case "-" -> lblResult.setText((num1-num2) + "");
                case "*" -> lblResult.setText((num1*num2) + "");
                case "/" -> lblResult.setText((num1/num2) + "");
            }
            addCalculation(String.valueOf(num1), operator, String.valueOf(num2), lblResult.getText());
            operator = ".";
        }
        else if(symbol.equals("Clear")) {
            lblResult.setText(String.valueOf(0.0));
            operator = ".";
        }
        else if(symbol.equals("HIST")){
            openHistoryWindow();
        }
        else {
            switch (symbol) {
                case "Plus" -> operator = "+";
                case "Minus" -> operator = "-";
                case "Multiply" -> operator = "*";
                case "Divide" -> operator = "/";
            }
            num1 = Double.parseDouble(lblResult.getText());
            lblResult.setText(String.valueOf(0.0));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This addresses the immediate question; there are other issues with your code which are too numerous to deal with.

The error message tells you the problem: `keyPress(...)` is an instance ("non-static") method, and you are trying to access it as though it is a static method (i.e. via the class name).

Note that `keyPress(...)` accesses instance variables, so you cannot make it static. Your only option is to access the method through the controller instance. Since you already retrieve that instance via `loader.getController()`, this is straightforward; just save it to an instance variable:

```
public class MainWindow extends Application implements EventHandler<KeyEvent> {


    private static Stage historyStage;

    private MainWindowController controller ;
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MainWindowInterface.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load());
        scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setTitle("Calculator");
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("../images/icon.png")));

        controller = loader.getController();
        controller.init(stage);

        stage.show();
        //scene.setOnKeyPressed(MainWindowController.handle());
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(this);

        // this will replace the handler from the previous line,
        // so is probably not what you want to do
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE){
                stage.close();
            }
        });
        createHistoryStage();
    }

    // ...

    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
        String valueOfKey = String.valueOf(event.getCode());
        controller.keyPress(valueOfKey);
    }

}
```

Comment: So the error is gone but the inputs don't get sent through. I tried putting a sout(valueOfKey) in handle but it doesn't print anything?

Comment: @RubenMoons Well, you set the `onKeyPressed` property twice, so of course it only has the second value.